# How can i get images from gallery in corona sdk?

Tags: lua, coronasdk

In my application how can i get images from gallery and use it with my application.please help me i searched in the net i could not get clear answer.give some suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

YOu can using [media.show](http://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/media/show.html)

```
media.show( media.PhotoLibrary, listener)
```

Answer (score -2):

Sorry, but you can't.

You can SAVE to the gallery though...